# Pythagorean triples in a triangle inside a rectangle

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

Suppose there's a right-angled triangle inside a rectangle in the following way:

[image: four right-angled triangles image]

(just take any right-angled rectangle, "rotate" it and draw a rectangle around it)

There are four right-angled triangles in that image.

Does there exist a triangle and rectangle combo so that all the resulting triangles have [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) as their sides?

Comment: Ah, this is related, it may help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182385/an-interesting-question-about-pythagorean-triples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>I realize this is rather hastily done but I'm at work so I'll have to fix this later.</s> Fixed, my earlier "solution" was super wrong check it out to find a great logical fallacy.

I checked the answer from the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182385/an-interesting-question-about-pythagorean-triples) you posted and this problem is a direct concequence. So let's look at the solution from the other question:

[image: pic from other question]

> Note that triangles $ABC$ and $CDE$ must be similar if $BCD$ is to be a straight line, so both must be built from integer multiples of the same primitive pythagorean triple $T= {a,b,c}$ with hypotenuse $c$.
>
> Suppose $ABC$ is $pT$ and $CDE$ is $qT$ then $AC=pc$ and $CE=qc$ and $AE^{2}=p^{2}c^{2}+q^{2}c^{2}$ so that $AE$ is divisible by $c$ and equals $rc$.
>
> You can build your trapezium from any pair of pythagorean triples (not necessarily primitive)
>
> $T={a,b,c}$ and $U= {p,q,r}$
>
> with $ABC = \{pa,pb,pc\}, CDE = \{qb,qa,qc\}, ACE = \{pc,qc,rc\}$.
>
> And this is essentially the only way of doing it.

Now lets keep going from where he left off and expand $BA$ to $G$ to make the right angled triangle $AGE$ and we'll see if it also has integer side lengths.

$$
AG = qb - pa \\
GE = pb + qa \\
AE = cr
$$

Yup it does.

That's it. But let's verify that it really is a right angled triangle:
$$
AG^{2} + GE^{2} = AE^{2} \\
\Leftrightarrow (qb - pa)^{2}+(pb + qa)^{2} = (rc)^{2} \\
\Leftrightarrow (qb)^{2}+(pa)^{2}+(pb)^{2}+(qa)^{2} = (rc)^{2} \\
\Leftrightarrow^{*} (qc)^{2} + (pc)^{2} =^{**} (rc)^{2}
$$

$*\: a, b, c$ is a pythagorean triplet
$**\: q, p, r$ is a pythagorean triplet

QED

Comment: I don't see how in the verification step the equivalences come from being Pythagorean triples... it's basic algebra. Otherwise excellent answer!

Comment: I saw that yesterdsy but I was tired the stars are fixed now

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  One example would be a rectangle as you have drawn, $100$ horizontal and $96$ vertical.  The left side is divided $75+21$ and the bottom is $72+28$.  The upper line is $100$, the left lower is $75$, and the right lower is $100$.  You can make one starting with  any Pythagorean triangle you like.  See the figure below.  $s=\sin \theta, c=\cos \theta$ are both rational based on your favorite triangle.  You need $\theta$ to be the small angle so you can double it. The labels on the segments come from trig, including the double angle formulas.  As all the sides are rational, scale up and you have integers.  In my example the top two triangles are both $75-100-125$, the lower left is $21-72-75$ and the right one is $28-96-100$

[image]

Comment: The answer is a little confusing... Yes, the middle triangle has sides $(35, 120, 125)$, so this example shows that such a combo does exist. I don't understand the general construction, though -- why are both marked angles at the top right $\theta$? Does it really hold for all such constructions? Why are $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ rational?

Comment: The two angles are both marked $\theta$ because I assumed the two top triangles are congruent.  They are both $s-c-1$ triangles before scaling up.  That allowed me to find the two $2\theta$ angles by geometry, then to find the other sides by using the double angle formula.  I have not proved that this is required, only that this construction works The drawing was confusing  because the lower point was much too far left.  I have replaced it.

Comment: Okay, so this is one possible construction. I still don't get why you can assume $\sin \theta$ to be rational, though... On your new image the center triangle is no longer right-angled (I wanted all four to be right-angled and have Pythagorean triples as sides)...

Comment: $\sin \theta$ is the ratio of two sides of the triangle.  Since the sides are integers, $\sin, \cos, \tan$ of the angles have to be rational.  Yes, the center triangle is right angled, as you can check from the side lengths.  I am just drawing by eye, so it doesn't look right angled.